# Java Swing: Jtree with star rating system on items

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, jtree

I display clickable items as results in a JTree and I need to get user feedback and do supervised learning using a star rating system so that future results are better. The goal is to have a star rater per item in the list.
To achieve this I am replacing the JCheckBox in [swing-checkbox-tree](https://github.com/scijava/swing-checkbox-tree) by [star rater](http://www.javaswingcomponents.com/product/rater).

However, I get one clickable panel(with star rater and a label) per item in the JList and this affects the behavior of the star rater.

How would I keep the behavior of the star rater after it is added to the swing-checkbox-tree?
following is my code:
CheckBoxNodeData.java

```
public class CheckBoxNodeData {

private String text;
private BigDecimal value;

public CheckBoxNodeData(final String text, final BigDecimal value) {
    this.text = text;
    this.value = value;
}

public BigDecimal getRating() {
    return value;
}

public void setRating(final BigDecimal value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(final String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "[" + text + "/" + value + "]";
}}
```

CheckBoxNodePanel.java

```
public class CheckBoxNodePanel extends JPanel {

public final JLabel label = new JLabel();
public final JSCRater rater = new JSCRater();

public CheckBoxNodePanel() {
    this.rater.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));

    // create the unselected painter
    SolidColorPainter unselectedPainter = new SolidColorPainter(Color.GRAY);

    // create the selected
    GradientColorPainter selectedPainter = new GradientColorPainter(Color.ORANGE, Color.YELLOW);

    // set the painters
    this.rater.setUnselectedPainter(unselectedPainter);
    this.rater.setSelectedPainter(selectedPainter);

    DefaultRaterModel raterModel = new DefaultRaterModel();

    // this will change the number of shapes to 5.
    raterModel.setNumShapes(5);

    // The DefaultRater allows the developer to specify
    // if the user may select whole shapes, half shapes or quarter shapes.
    raterModel.setSelection(Selection.FULL);

    this.rater.setRaterModel(raterModel);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(rater, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}}
```

CheckBoxNodeEditor.java

```
public class CheckBoxNodeEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TreeCellEditor {

private final CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();

private final JTree theTree;

public CheckBoxNodeEditor(final JTree tree) {
    theTree = tree;
}

@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    final CheckBoxNodePanel panel = renderer.getPanel();
    final CheckBoxNodeData checkBoxNode = new CheckBoxNodeData(panel.label.getText(), panel.rater.getRating());
    return checkBoxNode;
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(final EventObject event) {
    if (!(event instanceof MouseEvent))
        return false;
    final MouseEvent mouseEvent = (MouseEvent) event;

    final TreePath path = theTree.getPathForLocation(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY());
    if (path == null)
        return false;

    final Object node = path.getLastPathComponent();
    if (!(node instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode))
        return false;
    final DefaultMutableTreeNode treeNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node;

    final Object userObject = treeNode.getUserObject();
    return userObject instanceof CheckBoxNodeData;
}

@Override
public Component getTreeCellEditorComponent(final JTree tree, final Object value, final boolean selected,
        final boolean expanded, final boolean leaf, final int row) {

    final Component editor = renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, true, expanded, leaf, row, true);

    // editor always selected / focused
    final RatingChangeListener rateChangeListener = new RatingChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void ratingChanged(RatingChangeEvent ratingChangeEvent) {
            if (stopCellEditing()) {
                System.out.println("**debug");
                fireEditingStopped();
            }

        }
    };

    if (editor instanceof CheckBoxNodePanel) {
        final CheckBoxNodePanel panel = (CheckBoxNodePanel) editor;
        panel.rater.addRatingChangeListener(rateChangeListener);
    }

    return editor;
}}
```

CheckBoxNodeRenderer.java

```
public class CheckBoxNodeRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {

private final CheckBoxNodePanel panel = new CheckBoxNodePanel();

private final DefaultTreeCellRenderer defaultRenderer =
    new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();

private final Color selectionForeground, selectionBackground;
private final Color textForeground, textBackground;

protected CheckBoxNodePanel getPanel() {
    return panel;
}

public CheckBoxNodeRenderer() {
    final Font fontValue = UIManager.getFont("Tree.font");
    if (fontValue != null) panel.label.setFont(fontValue);

    final Boolean focusPainted =
        (Boolean) UIManager.get("Tree.drawsFocusBorderAroundIcon");
    //panel.rater.setFocusPainted(focusPainted != null && focusPainted);

    selectionForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionForeground");
    selectionBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.selectionBackground");
    textForeground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textForeground");
    textBackground = UIManager.getColor("Tree.textBackground");
}

// -- TreeCellRenderer methods --

@Override
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(final JTree tree,
    final Object value, final boolean selected, final boolean expanded,
    final boolean leaf, final int row, final boolean hasFocus)
{
    CheckBoxNodeData data = null;
    if (value instanceof DefaultMutableTreeNode) {
        final DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;
        final Object userObject = node.getUserObject();
        if (userObject instanceof CheckBoxNodeData) {
            data = (CheckBoxNodeData) userObject;
        }
    }

    final String stringValue =
        tree.convertValueToText(value, selected, expanded, leaf, row, false);
    panel.label.setText(stringValue);
    panel.rater.setRating(new BigDecimal(0));

    panel.setEnabled(tree.isEnabled());

    if (selected) {
        panel.setForeground(selectionForeground);
        panel.setBackground(selectionBackground);
        panel.label.setForeground(selectionForeground);
        panel.label.setBackground(selectionBackground);
    }
    else {
        panel.setForeground(textForeground);
        panel.setBackground(textBackground);
        panel.label.setForeground(textForeground);
        panel.label.setBackground(textBackground);
    }

    if (data == null) {
        return defaultRenderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value,
            selected, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);
    }

    panel.label.setText(data.getText());
    panel.rater.setRating(data.getRating());

    return panel;
}}
```

CheckBoxTreeSample.java

```
public class CheckBoxTreeSample {

public static void main(final String args[]) {
    final DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");


    final DefaultMutableTreeNode browsing =
        new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Browsing");
    add(browsing, "Notify when downloads complete", new BigDecimal(0));
    add(browsing, "Disable script debugging", new BigDecimal(0));
    add(browsing, "Use AutoComplete", new BigDecimal(0));
    add(browsing, "Browse in a new process", new BigDecimal(0));
    root.add(browsing);

    final DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    final JTree tree = new JTree(treeModel);

    final CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();
    tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);

    final CheckBoxNodeEditor editor = new CheckBoxNodeEditor(tree);
    tree.setCellEditor(editor);
    tree.setEditable(true);

    // listen for changes in the selection
    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(final TreeSelectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": selection changed");
        }
    });

    // listen for changes in the model (including check box toggles)
    treeModel.addTreeModelListener(new TreeModelListener() {

        @Override
        public void treeNodesChanged(final TreeModelEvent e) {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": nodes changed");
        }

        @Override
        public void treeNodesInserted(final TreeModelEvent e) {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": nodes inserted");
        }

        @Override
        public void treeNodesRemoved(final TreeModelEvent e) {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": nodes removed");
        }

        @Override
        public void treeStructureChanged(final TreeModelEvent e) {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": structure changed");
        }
    });

    // show the tree onscreen
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("CheckBox Tree");
    final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static DefaultMutableTreeNode add(
    final DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, final String text,
    final BigDecimal rating)
{
    final CheckBoxNodeData data = new CheckBoxNodeData(text, rating);
    final DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(data);
    parent.add(node);
    return node;
}
```

}

Comment: An example using `Outline` is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20Outline%20isCellEditable).

Comment: For better help sooner post a [mcve].